# sum of bessel functions identity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anyone have a slick proof for this result?

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}J_{j+m+n}(x)J_{j+m}(x) = \frac{x}{2n}\left[J_{j+1}(x)J_{j+n}(x) - J_{j}(x)J_{j+n+1}(x)\right]$$

I found it in a paper (http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~antal/Mypapers/spin99.pdf last page in appendix) without any particular reference and couldn't pick up the bread crumbs from Watson or Abramowitz. I was hoping to retrace the steps and potentially find a closed-form expression for

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}J_{j+2m+n}(x)J_{j+2m}(x),$$

if it can be simplified similarly.

Comment: I found the answer to your question (I was actually studying the same paper and the same equations ...)http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018701/sum-of-bessel-functions/2019959#2019959