# Sum of Bessel functions

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

I have two integers $m$ and $n$ and a real $t$. I'm trying to prove the following identity :

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{+\infty}J_{j+n}(t)J_{j+m}(t)=\frac{t}{2(m-n)}(J_{m-1}(t)J_n(t)-J_m(t)J_{n-1}(t))$$

where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. I don't really know where to start to prove this.

Comment: Did you check whether it was true numerically (e.g. with Maple or something)?

Comment: Maybe start with the [series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J.CE.B1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{equation}
J_{j+n}(t)J_{j+m}(t)=\frac{t}{2(m-n)}\left(\frac{2}{t}[j+m-(j+n)]J_{j+n}(t)J_{j+m}(t)\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
J_{j+n}(t)J_{j+m}(t)=\frac{t}{2(m-n)}\left(\frac{2}{t}[j+m]J_{j+n}(t)J_{j+m}(t)-\frac{2}{t}[j+n]J_{j+n}(t)J_{j+m}(t)\right)
\end{equation}
Then using the recurrence relation on Bessel functions
$$ \frac{2n}{t}J_n(t)=J_{n-1}(t)+J_{n+1}(t)$$
One finds terms the general term of a telescopic sum leading to the result conjectured in the question.