# Series of product of Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

The Christoffel-Darboux formula applied to Bessel functions states that

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{+\infty}J_{j+n}(t)J_{j+m}(t)=\frac{t}{2(m-n)}\left(J_{m-1}(t)J_n(t)-J_m(t)J_{n-1}(t) \right)$$

See for instance [Sum of Bessel functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018701/sum-of-bessel-functions)

Is there a similar simplification for the following sum ?

$$\mathcal{I}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{+\infty}J_{2j+n}(t)J_{2j+m}(t)$$

The sum is taken over all even integers. The best I could find is this series which is close http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/23/01/0016/ but there is no reference or proof of this identity.

Comment: So if you follow the same proof as before \begin{equation}
J_{2j+n}(t)J_{2j+m}(t)=\frac{t}{2(m-n)}\left( J_{2j+m-1}(t) J_{2j+n}(t) + J_{2j+m+1} (t) J_{2j+n}(t)-J_{2j+n+1}(t)J_{2j+m}(t) - J_{2j+n-1}(t)J_{2j+m}(t)\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: I do agree that you can rewrite this product in such a way, but in this case there is no telescopic sum, how would you proceed ?

Comment: Say you call the answer $A_{m,n}$. If you sum the above equation on $j$ it looks like you're getting $A_{m,n}$ satisfying some discrete Laplace type equation. May not be useful, but worth including the strategy of the previous question as something you've already tried.