# Closed form for an infinite series involving a product of two Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I've come across this infinite series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}J_{k+m}(z)J_{k+n}(z)$$

where m and n are integers. I suspect that there is a closed form for it but I haven't found one for it. I skimmed through Watson's book and couldn't find either. Does anyone know of a closed form for it? Thanks.

Comment: I have replaced your image by the text `$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}J_{k+m}(z)J_{k+n}(z)$`. Please learn the basics of Latex...

Comment: Is there a connection with the [Christoffel-Darboux formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2018701) ?

Comment: Thanks for editing it!.
I'm aware of the Christoffel-Darboux formula but it does not seem to be connected to it.

Comment: Maybe you can find some indications in the big reference book of Watson "A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions" available on line on ResearchGate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I skimmed through the book of Watson before I posted the question and couldn't find something that looks like the series I asked about. I'll recheck anyway.

Comment: Another advice for next time: This kind of information ("not found in the book of Watson") could had be given in the question, enriching it.

Comment: You can put it into [KDF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html) form and look for a decomposition formula, but there are better methods. There could also be an [Appel function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series) form. Also, please add what you have tried to the question.